# How to read rPi camera hardware information that which type of camera sensor( imx219 or OV5647) is being used in camera module?

Tags: raspbian, hardware, camera, raspicam, picamera

I want to read the camera hardware spec to ensure which type of camera sensor (like imx219 or OV5647 etc) is being used in the rPi camera module for camera module v1 and v2.

Is there any method to read that hardware information from the Raspbian os? Thank you.